# Location provider check doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, location

I'm new to Android. Now I'm learning how Location service works. My problem is that I cannot obtain location source when connecting both listeners, GPS and Network, to one object. Here is my code:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location.getProvider() == LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) {
        textView1.setText("Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + ", Long: " + location.getLongitude() + " by GPS");
    } else if (location.getProvider() == LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) {
        textView1.setText("Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + ", Long: " + location.getLongitude() + " by network");
    }
}
```

and this code never updates the TextView. I tried it in different situations, indoor/outdoor, turned GPS on/off, and nothing... I'm very confused because the following code where I don't check the provider:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    textView1.setText("Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + ", Long: " + location.getLongitude());
}
```

works very well.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you given proper permissions in manifest.xml ?

Comment: can you check single listener works or not ?

Comment: check your logcat for any error messages

Comment: yes... Manifest and single listeners work correctly. When I don't check provider, everything works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not obvious, but for some reason Android's `LocationManager` uses string to define provider constants. So you need to check strings using `.equals()`, not `==`:

```
if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (location.getProvider == LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
```

don't ever compare a string with ==, use this

```
 if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
```

Answer (score 0):

`LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` & `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` are string constants hence you need to compare using `equals()` method of String class like below,

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    if (location.getProvider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        textView1.setText("Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + ", Long: " + location.getLongitude() + " by GPS");
    } else if (location.getProvider.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        textView1.setText("Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + ", Long: " + location.getLongitude() + " by network");
    }
}
```